# Combobox does not dispatch a change event when text is same as previous text

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

If you have a Flex Spark Combobox and enter a value in the text field and press enter a Event.CHANGE event was dispatched. Then if you set the selectedItem to null it erases the value. But if you type in the same value as before and press enter no change event is dispatched. If you enter a different value and press enter a change event is dispatched.

Is there any work around or fix for this?

**Steps:**

1. Create a combox, add an event listener and run the application
2. Type in the value, "test" and press enter
3. In the event set the combobox.selectedItem to null
4. Type in the same value, "test" again and press enter

**Expected Behavior:**
 Change event is dispatched again.

**Actual Behavior:**
 Change event is not dispatched. Type in a different value and press enter and the change event is dispatched correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ComboBox.previousTextInputText is not being cleared out and that may be the reason it's not dispatching a change event.

It appears that setting ComboBox.openOnInput to false achieves the desired behavior. This is not a real fix but seems to work.